# stop autopost back on default value of dropdownlist asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist(autopostback enabled) in my project in binded through sqldatasource, i have added an initial value to it using list item. The problem is the page is being postbacked even when selecting the initial value which i dont want. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListTheme" runat="server" 
 DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceTheme" DataTextField="h_theme" 
 DataValueField="h_theme" Height="30px" Width="30%" 
 AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True"> 
 <asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" Value="-1" />   
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: You mean you want to select initial value or not after postback?

Comment: Thanks mate, i already got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial item as selected initially

`<asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" Selected="True" Value="-1" />`

Comment: Thanks for ur hlp. i got wht i was looking for,

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
onchange="if(this.selectedIndex == 0)return false;"
```

event to drop down list.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, this is exactly what i was looking for.